# get the value from nested node firebase databse

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get all the value of Nutrients node, but it return null.

this is my database :

[image]

I have recipe node with values, then i have nested child "Nutrients"
i want to get all the values of it

```
data_ref_recipe = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipes");
data_ref_recipe.child(recipe_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         recipe_name = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("recipe_name").getValue());
        ingrediants = String.valueOf((snapshot.child("ingrediants").getValue()));
        instructions = String.valueOf((snapshot.child("instructions").getValue()));

        carb = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Nutrients").child("carb").getValue());
        fat = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Nutrients").child("fat").getValue());
        protien = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Nutrients").child("protine").getValue());
        calories = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Nutrients").child("calories").getValue());

        rcarb.setText(carb);
        rfat.setText(fat);
        rprotien.setText(protien);
        rcalories.setText(calories);
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

I get all the values of ricpe. but i get null for Nutrients.

This is my recipe class :

```
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

String recipe_id,uid, recipe_name , ingrediants ,instructions ,recipe_type , cook_time, quantity, date;
Uri recipe_image ;

Double carb,fat, protine, calories;

//for firebase
public Recipe (){}

public Recipe (Double carb, Double fat, Double protine, Double calories){
    this.carb = carb;
    this.fat = fat;
    this.protine = protine;
    this.calories = calories;
}

public Recipe(String recipe_id,String uid, String recipe_name, String ingrediants, String instructions, String recipe_type, String cook_time, String quantity , String date) {
    this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.recipe_name = recipe_name;
    this.ingrediants = ingrediants;
    this.instructions = instructions;
    this.recipe_type = recipe_type;
    this.cook_time = cook_time;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.date = date ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an additional colon (`:`) in the `Nutrients:` key, which you'll also need to include in the code:

```
DataSnapshot nutrients = snapshot.child("Nutrients:");
carb = String.valueOf(nutrients.child("carb").getValue());
fat = String.valueOf(nutrients.child("fat").getValue());
protien = String.valueOf(nutrients.child("protine").getValue());
calories = String.valueOf(nutrients.child("calories").getValue());
```

If this still doesn't work, check the exact spelling and spaces of the node name in the console.

---

Also (not the problem here, but in general) you should never leave `onCancelled` empty, as it means you're ignoring possible errors. At its minimum, it should be:

```
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
    throw databaseError.toException(); 
}
```